# How to set selection of whole row in silevis/reactgrid from context menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to select whole row (or multiple rows) from the right click context menu.
Is there a possibility to do that in @silevis/reactgrid ?

There is option to select whole row
`enableRowSelection`
by clicking the first cell from the row but it is not what I need.
I want exactly the same function to run from right click context menu.

If there is available function to set selection range - it will be also helpful because I can pass there row index and first and last column of the row.

Any ideas ??

---

Rafal